# Builder widget for ChangeNotifier in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-change-notifier

### Background

- A `ValueNotifier` has a `ValueListenableBuilder` widget.
- A `Stream` has a `StreamBuilder` widget.
- A `Future` has a `FutureBuilder` widget.

### Question

- What is the builder for `ChangeNotifier`?

### What I tried

I tried using a `ValueListenableBuilder` with `ChangeNotifier` but `ChangeNotifier` doesn't implement `ValueListenable`.

I know I could use `ChangeNotifierProvider` from the `Provider` package, but I'd like to know if there is a solution that doesn't require a third-party package.

Comment: `AnimatedBuilder` (or `AnimatedWidget` if you want some custom class that extends `AnimatedWidget`)

Comment: @pskink, Interesting! I wouldn't have guessed that from the name.

Comment: Sometimes, I feel like walking through the same steps you have walked. Whenever I try to build on your 'minimalist' architecture, I see your solutions popping up. My page's ViewModel/Controller/Manager class is a `ChangeNotifier`, and within it lies multiple simple/complex `ValueNotifiers`. UI is notified accordingly via the whole ViewModel `notifyListeners()` or its fine-tuned property ValueNotifiers. I use `ChangeNotifier` for the ViewModel, because a `ValueNotifier` subclass requires equality check  `==` for notification. Which means overriding said `==`+`hashCode` or using `Equatable`.

Comment: Because of the above, I was looking for a `ChangeNotifier` builder. And this question/answer fit perfectly for this particular scenario.

Comment: @om-ha, I like `ChangeNotifier` for its simplicity and ease of use. I've never had to override `==` and `hashCode` in my value notifier, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of today, AnimatedBuilder is renamed and update as **ListenableBuilder**

Hope documents will be updated soon but you can see related issue and examples here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/116543/files

Comment: Thanks for mentioning ListenableBuilder ! Really cool they finally made a class that makes more sense namewise !

Answer (score 24):

Use `ListenableBuilder`.

This is a supplemental answer demonstrating using a `ListenableBuilder` to rebuild the UI on a change from a `ChangeNotifier`.

It's just the standard counter app.

*counter_model.dart*

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class CounterModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  int _counter = 0;

  int get count => _counter;

  void increment() {
    _counter++;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

*main.dart*

```dart
import 'counter_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _counterModel = CounterModel();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            ListenableBuilder(
              listenable: _counterModel,
              builder: (context, child) {
                return Text(
                  '${_counterModel.count}',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _counterModel.increment,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

*Update: Previously this answer demonstrated the use of `AnimatedBuilder`.*

**Note**: In this particular case (as in most cases), a `ValueNotifier` and `ValueListenableBuilder` would be sufficient. See [Flutter state management for minimalists](https://suragch.medium.com/flutter-state-management-for-minimalists-4c71a2f2f0c1?sk=6f9cedfb550ca9cc7f88317e2e7055a0).

Answer (score 19):

ChangeNotifier is a direct implementation of the Listenable Widget and for the Listenable, you can use AnimatedBuilder, which triggers rebuilds from a Listenable without passing back a specific value
Also, your class could extend from ChangeNotifier and add new capability to it and you can create a custom Builder widget base on these new functionalities

Answer (score 4):

You can wirte a simple widget by yourself.
use `setState` as a listener for a `ChangeNotifier`.

```dart
class ChangeNotifierBuilder<T extends ChangeNotifier> extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChangeNotifierBuilder({
    Key? key,
    required this.value,
    required this.builder,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final T value;

  final Widget Function(BuildContext context, T value) builder;

  @override
  _ChangeNotifierBuilderState<T> createState() =>
      _ChangeNotifierBuilderState<T>();
}

class _ChangeNotifierBuilderState<T extends ChangeNotifier>
    extends State<ChangeNotifierBuilder<T>> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    widget.value.addListener(_listener);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant ChangeNotifierBuilder<T> oldWidget) {
    if (widget.value != oldWidget.value) {
      _miggrate(widget.value, oldWidget.value, _listener);
    }
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.value.removeListener(_listener);
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _miggrate(Listenable a, Listenable b, void Function() listener) {
    a.removeListener(listener);
    b.addListener(listener);
  }

  void _listener() {
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.builder(context, widget.value);
  }
}
```

Comment: In `_miggrate(..)` function, it shoud be `b.removeListener()` and `a.addListener()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use consumer for Change and the build of your UI!
Try out these - https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple

Comment: The `Consumer` widget is part of the provider package and I was looking for a non-third-party solution. However, reading your link was helpful since it has been updated since I last read it.

Answer (score 1):

The builder for `ChangeNotifierProvider`, `ChangeNotifierProvider.value` and other providers is a `Consumer`:

```dart
ChangeNotifierProvider(
  create: (context) => CounterModel(),
  child: Consumer<CounterModel>(
    builder: (context, model, child) {
      return Text('${model.count}');
    }
  ),
),
```

Comment: I think it needs to be `ChangeNotifierProvider<CounterModel>(...)`